# Can’t bind to ‘ngModel’ since it isn’t a known property of ‘input’

Tags: angular, typescript

My App.module.ts is below i add the FormsModule reference but still its showing error "Can’t bind to ‘ngModel’ since it isn’t a known property of ‘input’"

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthenticationRoutingModule } from './authentication/authentication-routing.module';
import { ZonesRoutingModule } from './zones/zones-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
   FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,

   ReactiveFormsModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
  ZonesRoutingModule,
  AuthenticationRoutingModule
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
  export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: please add component details will help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I Forget to import FormsModule in my Other Module file